# Perl cpan DBD::Oracle installation error

Tags: perl, dbi, oracle-call-interface, oracle-xe, strawberry-perl

I'm using Oracle XE 11.2 on Windows 7. When I try to run on perl shell `cpanm DBD::Oracle` I received this work log

`-> FAIL Configure failed for DBD-Oracle-1.68.`

with a portion of explanation

`The ORACLE_HOME environment variable value (C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/bin;) is not valid.
  It must be set to hold the path to an Oracle installation directory
  on this machine (or a machine with a compatible architecture).`

My Environment Variables - system variables contain `PATH = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;...`

What is the exact Oracle installation directory for XE 11.2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider changing your perl (32 vs 64bit) and/or using [oracle instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html). There is also perl which comes with  every oracle installation with working dbd::oracle.

Comment: I don't think it likes the semicolon.

Comment: Yes, semicolon is partially my problem as from Lajos example stated there's no semicolon. And I assume my OS is 32-bit where I installed strawberryperl 32-bit, it is actually 64-bit with no OCI installed. SO I am trying now to install the proper stawberryperl and figuring out how to install Oracle instant client (OCI).

Answer (score 2):

The `/bin` at the end is suspicious, ORACLE_HOME shouldn't contain it.
But theoretically everything should be fine by default. (If you didn't renamed/moved anything.)

Anyway if it is a local installation `ORACLE_HOME` should be:

```
C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server
```

Details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/connecting.htm